# Regular expression matching javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable which can get any of the below values. x represents any alphanumeric character and the string can be of any length

```
/xxxxxxx
/xxxx/xxxx?xxx=xx
/xxxxx/
/xxxxxxxxx?
/xxxxxxx/xxxx/xxx
/xx/xxx.jpg
/xxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx
/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx
/xxxx?xx=yy&abc=def&xyz=lmn
```

The goal is to get everything before the "?" character in the string if ? character exists
if it doesn't exist then it should simply get the string

i have written a regular expression as follows:

```
var  pattern = /\/.*\?/;
```

The only issue is this pattern does not stop at the ? and return the whole string. Any clues how this can be fixed ?

Comment: Not tested, but tried this? /[\/.*^\?]+/; specifying that it should match X which doesn't have ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The goal is to get everything before the "?" character in the string if ? character exists if it doesn't exist then it should simply get the string

```
/^[^?]*/
```

This works because `^` means start of input, and `[^?]` means a character that is not a `?`, and `*` means zero or more, so the whole means "starting from input, zero or more characters that are not question marks".

That has the effect of matching from the start of the input to the first question mark or the end of input whichever comes first.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
var  pattern = /\/.*?(\?|$)/;
```

Comment: Yes - but not as neat as the accepted answer. I was working with your regex as a starting point, and taking what you asked for very literally, rather than looking at the underlying problem. For posterity - I added `?` to make `.*` un-greedy, and match as little as possible, then added `$` to match the end of the string, and put it in `or` group with the `\?` so that the match, un-greedy as it is, would have to be pulled either to the end of the string, or to a question mark at least.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a regex here, you could simply use `indexOf()` and `substr()`:

```
var qPos = url.indexOf('?');
var path = (qPos === -1) ? url : url.substring(0, qPos);
```